# htaccess like for like domain redirect

Tags: .htaccess

I am using this rewrite to redirect my other domains to my main domain name, and keep the path intact.

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule (.*) https://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

which works great, but can I also keep the subdomain intact too?

for example, if the URL visited is `sub1.domain2.com/path` can it redirect to `sub1.example.com/path`

Comment: @anubhava sorry I'm not sure what you mean?

Comment: ah, no the main domain is under /home/username/public_html and each other is under /home/username/domains/sub1.domain2.com etc

Comment: could i use something like `RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*\.)$` and `RewriteRule ^.*$ http://%1.domain.com/$0 [L`]

Comment: i dont want to rewrite the url, I want to actually redirect and change the URL itself too

Comment: But what do you mean by `but can I also keep the subdomain intact too` ?

Comment: so i want to redirect all urls to the main domain (domain.com) so it'll redirect `domain2.com => domain.com`, `domain2.com/path => domain.com/path`, `sub.domain2.com => sub.domain.com`, `sub.domain2.com/path => sub.domain.com/path`

Comment: so essentially, everything will redirect to one single domain keeping any subdomains and trailing path

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use these redirect rules:

```
RewriteEngine On

# subdomain redirect
# sub.domain2.com => sub.example.com
# sub.domain2.com/path => sub.domain.com/path
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !\.main-domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?!www\.)([^.]+)\.[^.]+\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://%1.main-domain.com%{REQUEST_URI} [L,NE,R=301]

# other redirect
# domain2.com => example.com
# domain2.com/path => example.com/path
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^main-domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://main-domain.com%{REQUEST_URI} [L,NE,R=301]
```

Comment: what does the `^(?!sub\.|domain\.)` in the RewriteCond? Do I need to change those values?

Comment: and the `^(sub)\.`

Comment: there are many domains i want to redirect, can I use regex to match anything?

Comment: there are over 50 domains, it would be huge. i'd prefer it to just redirect all if possible

Comment: can we do the same for `#other redirect` too?

Comment: but i dont know what sub is going to be, there are many different ones

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/212812/discussion-between-anubhava-and-charlie).